# Releasing android camera object fails on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working with Android Camera API. I am developing an app to take photos and just after I take a picture, I want to release the camera. But, Camera is not being released on some devices like ericson, xperia and few others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE then the camera will take care of itself as long as you define onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data).

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, I needed to release camera only in `surfaceDestroyed()` method, in activity which implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback`.

```
@Override public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    camera.release();
    hasSurface = false;
}
```

Because, in some devices, releasing hardware resources is a slow process, which can effect immediate processing. Releasing camera in `surfaceDestroyed()` makes sure that surface preview is stopped/destroyed and then, we can release the camera.

Comment: and do anybody know what this                                          03-29 20:12:51.133: DEBUG/SemcCameraHardware(1097): release E
03-29 20:12:51.623: DEBUG/SemcCameraHardware(1097): release X
    because whenever the activty hangs only release E comes but no release X........ and on success both comes in log output   .... its urgent if anybody have idea about this